# PowerView not showing date measure

Tags: ssas, dax, powerview

I have an SSAS tabular model where I define a measure like so:

```
EndDate := LASTDATE(myTable[Date])
```

I can see and use this measure in Excel and in SSMS, however it does not appear in the field list in PowerView.

I know of a workaround like the following that will show a date like `20140721`:

```
EndDate := YEAR (LASTDATE( myTable[Date] )) * 10000
  + MONTH (LASTDATE( myTable[Date] )) * 100
  + DAY (LASTDATE( myTable[Date] ))
```

I need to be able to show a more friendly date then this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Power View in Excel only shows numeric model measures.